# How do I access speech input level during voice recognition

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, voice-recognition

I've got my voice recognition textarea all set up so i can speak to a text area

```
<span id="button" onclick="toggleStartStop()">CLICK ME!</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var recognizing;
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.onresult = function (event) {
    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        TEXTAREA.value += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      }
    }
  }

  function reset() {
    recognizing = false;
    button.innerHTML = "Click to Speak";
  }

  function toggleStartStop() {
    if (recognizing) {
      recognition.stop();
      reset();
    } else {
      recognition.start();
      recognizing = true;
      button.innerHTML = "Click to Stop";
    }

    function speak(text, callback) {
      var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      u.text = text;
      u.lang = 'en-US';
      u.onend = function () {
        if (callback) {
          callback();
        }
      };

      u.onerror = function (e) {
        if (callback) {
          callback(e);
        }
      };
      speechSynthesis.speak(u);
    }
  }
</script>
```

but I'm trying to add voice indication to it like how googles voice search is.

```
http://www.stateofdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/google-voice-search.png
```

I have searched everything I can think of only finding results to voice search, nothing to do with the input level indication (like the circle that grows based on how loud you speak) from google. So I figured I'd ask, how can I do something like that?

Also all the tutorials I have found to make voice recognition what I came up with is the best I can do, I have dont know much js.  So another question how can I make the code I have type as I speak, the way i have it now it will only insert the text when i pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get audio stream at the same time as speech is going and calculate the level yourself. For now the level is not supported in speech recognition API. Code should look like this:

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
    {
        audio: true
    }, 
    function(stream) 
    {
        // "that" is my wrapping object's scope
        that.stream = stream;

        var liveSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var levelChecker = context.createJavaScriptNode(that.bufSize, 1 ,1);

        liveSource.connect(levelChecker);
        levelChecker.connect(context.destination);
        levelChecker.onaudioprocess = function(event) 
        {
            var buf = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            var len = buf.length;
            var rms = 0;

            // Iterate through buffer
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            {
                rms += Math.abs(buf[i]);
            }
            rms = Math.sqrt(rms / len);
            that.levelCheckerCB(rms);
        };
    }
);
```

useful discussion is [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-html5/AidRiQbJ1Kg).

Comment: `#createJavaScriptNode` has been renamed to `#createScriptProcessor`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createJavaScriptNode